# The Oracle ManagedDataAccess Client is returning me Decimal type for both number and number(38)/number(38, 0)

Tags: c#, oracle, oracle-manageddataaccess

I have created table with three columns which have type number, number(38) and number(38, 0) in oracle. I am using ManageDataAccess client. It's retrieving me decimal type for all three columns.
I tried to modify the App.config file after looking at the below link:
[entity type mapping](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ODPNT/entityDataTypeMapping.htm#ODPNT8300)

I have modified App.config file as below for my use case:

```
<oracle.manageddataaccess.client>
<version number="*">
  <edmMappings>
       <edmMapping dataType="number">
           <add name="int64" precision="38" />
      </edmMapping>
   </edmMappings>
</version>
```

But still client is not retrieving me int64 type. 
Can you please help me to resolve the issue?

FYI: It's not web application

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be Decimal, not Int64

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E63277_01/win.121/e63268/entityDataTypeMapping.htm#ODPNT8300